# Change Archon keybindings

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

In the Wizard's Archon mode, the ability keybindings (1–4, mouse left & right clicks) are different than my normal keybindings, so switching between two setups leaves me teleporting into the crowd. I prefer my normal keybindings over Archon's, but realize that I can change my normal keybindings to match that of Archon's to minimize confusion. But is there a way to change the keybindings of Archon?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Answer (score 2):

Wizards have been asking for this since launch. Still doesn't look like it's ever going to happen.

Instead, we just change our out-of-Archon bindings to closely match our in-Archon bindings. That, or get used to the different bindings between the modes.